# ORA-12505. TNS: listener dos not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I cannot connect to Oracle database from SQL plus. This is the error message that I get:

```
Status: Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505. TNS: listener dos not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

This is the configuration of ***listener.ora:***

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.104)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

***sqlnet.ora:***

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

ADR_BASE = /u01/app/oracle
```

***tnsnames.ora:***

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.104)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracle)
    )
  )
```

How I can solve the problem?

***P.S***
This is the output of the command lsnrctl status

```
[oracle@localhost bin]$ ./lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-JAN-2013 14:38:00

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                08-JAN-2013 14:37:06
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 54 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.104)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
[oracle@localhost bin]$
```

Comment: What does `lsnrctl status` say?

Comment: Well, you can clearly see there is no service named oracle registered in that listener. Did you start the database?

Comment: Yes I started the database. How I can add service? Maybe I need to add something into the listener's configuration files?

Comment: Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you set the service_names for the database? That will specify the list of services registered with the listener. You can "alter system register" to prompt the instance to register with the listener.

Comment: I'm new to Oracle. I work with it since two weeks. Would you explain it more deeply, please?

Comment: According to the `uptime` on your `lsnrctl status` output, you'd only just started the listener; if the listener starts after the database it can take a little while to register running instances/services (unless you manually `alter system register` as David suggested), so you can check that again? (Though it must have been running earlier to get the `ORA-12505`). I'd probably expect it to show a service name, but one that doesn't match what you've put in your `tnsnames.ora` - maybe with a domain suffix, maybe not called `oracle` at all.